# Unobtrusive bugged out when array is involved

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have the following call:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Selections[0].Name)
```

In both instances, I tag the `SelectedName` and `Name` respectively with the following annotations

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide required value")]
```

However SelectedName prints the correct unobtrusive html attributes:

```
<input id="SelectedName" name="SelectedName" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please provide required value">
```

Where as the m.Selections[0].Name display as follow:

```
<input id="Selections_0__Name" name="Selections[0].Name" value="" type="text">
```

What gives? I can't believe this scenario has been overlooked in MVC4, it seems like a fairly common use case. How would I validate a view model that is an array or contains an array?

=====================EDIT adding code for the ViewModels for clarity=====================

```
public class ContainerVM
{
    [Required]
    public string SelectedName {get;set;}
    public MemberVM[] Selections {get;set;}
}

public class MemberVM
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get;set; }
}
```

=====================Forms ====================

```
@using MyProject.Models;
@model ContainerVM
@{
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext(); //This is just a hack because the parent isn't defined yet.
}

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCptGroupId)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CptGroupSelections[0].Name)
```

Comment: please share your declaration for Selections as well as your annotation

Comment: So, maybe I misunderstood. You haven't annotated the array?

Comment: OIC, yes, the **member (Name) of the array Model is required!**

Comment: @DaveA Nope, I annotated the member type of the array.

Comment: please share your entire Form. I'm hoping something will catch

Comment: TRY THIS change your array to public ICollection<MemberVM>. If that doesn't work, I'm thinkin custom validation attribute

Answer (score 2):

I hesitate to push an answer before getting more feedback, but

`[required]` annotation cannot be applied to arrays or complex objects.

You can apply `[required]` annotation for specific elements of a class or even a member of a nested class.

Obviously we all know we can annotate the classic

```
[required]
public string SelectedName {get; set;}
```

and this should work. I can't speak to this issue.

But, conversely annotation on an array of strings

```
[required]
public string[] SelectedName {get;set;}
```

**would fail.** for this to succeed, you would have to annotate each element of the Model.

similarly if we tried to annotate a nested model with members 
    [required]
    public SelectionsModel Selections {get;set;}

**this too would fail.**

worst of all, it looks like you are trying to annotate an array of models
    [required]
    public SelectionsModel Selections[] {get;set;}

**and this again would fail.**

---

***What should work(though i haven't tried):***

**Annotate each element of the nested Model Selections.**

Then each element of each model of the array should require input.

```
    public class SelectionsModel 
    {
        [required]
        public string name {get; set;}
        [required]
        public int age { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Dave, I am already doing the later. I am annotating each element of the array. And it's failing.

Comment: @Alwyn: Krp. Please share your model declaration and annotation. Maybe we can spot some ickies.

Comment: I am having the same issue, unobtrusive is not fired for the validation.